# Illustrator - How to create one outline stroke for overlapping transparent objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have some overlapping transparent paths in illustrator like:

[image]

The goal would be to create an outline stroke for that group of paths. Whatever I do with path combinations, it will destroy either colors, or delete some of the paths etc.

I tried with Shaper Tool. This let me select the single paths. But when applying stroke, they all get completely stroked:

[image: image2]

But I would like to have it just around the outline contour. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all paths and copy them
2. Hide all paths
3. Paste in front
4. Unite all the shapes (Pathfinder window)
5. Apply the desired path and a fill of "None"
6. Unhide hidden paths